# Minimum number of frames needed on an x86 processor

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, x86

I am implementing virtual memory in PINTOS running on x86 ,I want to know the  minimum number of frames needed for a process on an x86 processor.
I found out that it depends on the maximum level of indirection supported by the underlying Instruction set architecture ,On x86 there is 1 level of indirection supported.
So 2 frames per process should be the minimum needed.
If the instruction size is more than 1byte long then it might cross page boundary and we will need 3 minimum frames.
Am I correct or is there more to deciding on the minimum number of frames to be given per process.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to make sense of this question, "frame" usually means stack frame.  Seems you're talking about virtual memory *pages*.  It isn't impossible to cram everything in one 4096 byte page if the code is small enough and you set the page protection so it can contain code, data and stack.  It doesn't have anything to do with instruction size or indirection.

Comment: @HansPassant: *page frame* is a quite common term in the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page directory - 1
Page table - 1
Instruction on a page boundary - 2
Source data on a page boundary - 2
Destination data on a page boundary - 2

So, 8 pages is what you may need for something like `REP MOVSW/D`.

Comment: A general purpose register like eax is  32 bit long.
when there is an instruction like 

    mov %eax,[MEM_LOC1]
    mov [MEM_LOC1], [MEM_LOC2]

In the second instruction,Can the source data  cross page boundary ?Is this the reason why you have given 2 frames for source and destination data?

Comment: `MOVSW/D` reads a (D)WORD from the location pointed to by DS:(E)SI and writes that (D)WORD to the location pointed to by ES:(E)DI. That's two data locations, each of which can be near a page boundary. And the instruction itself can cross a page boundary if it has a prefix (address size override, operand size override, segment override, rep). That's how you get 6 pages for `REP MOVSW/D`.